# Is there a way to send process RAM usage in disk?

Tags: linux, process

If I want the process PID 666 to stop using my CPU i can use `kill -SIGSTOP 666`.
And I can use this process normally after a `kill -SIGCONT 666`.
But this process is still using my memory.

Is there a way to send the data stored in RAM into let's say the disk (maybe swap), and to restore it of course afterwards ?

Comment: Any drop in memory usage if you flush buffers, `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` ?

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for (i. e. moving the process' memory usage to swap) will happen automatically if the kernel needs to make room in RAM for an active process while the process in question is in a stopped state.

Comment: Upvoted as this is an interesting answer, I can manually put the process back in memory with `sudo swapoff -a`. But is there a manual way to put it in swap ?

Comment: Start interacting with the process again.  The kernel will see this and, if there is not resource contention, automatically pull it back out of swap for you.

Comment: I have no problem getting it off swap, i just want to know how to put it inside at will. (When I want, not when ram is full)

Comment: There are two things that will make the Kernel move processes into Swap:  Resource contention (i. e. RAM is exhausted and more memory is allocated), or "Swappiness", which is (put simply) the kernel's aggressiveness with determining which processes are "idle" enough to be moved out to swap.  Without mucking about with cgroups, it's essentially impossible to do this at an at-will level per process.  Just let the kernel do its job and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [cgroup](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt), add process to it and use swappiness (`/proc/sys/vm/swappiness`) per cgroup to control swap usage of that particular group. You can also forcibly *prevent* memory of particular process from being swapped with mlock (see `man mlock` and `man mlockall`).